# No reply after almost two months since the first interview

Tags: funding, postdocs, job-search, email, interview

At the beginning of March I applied for a postdoc position that was very close to the research topic of my PhD. I also sent an email to the Professor who posted the position in order to persuade him of my qualifications and my willingness to obtain the position.

On the 18th of March he replied to my email and we scheduled a zoom meeting on the 22nd of March. The meeting went well, and he told me that there will be another formal meeting after a month (around 22nd of April). However, the 22nd passed and no meeting took place.

After I sent him another email on the 27th of April, he told me that there have been issues related to the funding at the faculty level and everything has been delayed, and that they promised him he will get an update in **the next few days**, he also promised he will keep me updated.

However, to this day I have not received any updates regarding the situation, and I am confused as to whether I need to contact him again. I don't want to look rude nor pesky, but I really want things to move forward and do the second interview as soon as possible.

Should I contact him now or should I wait more? I believe **the next few days** means 3-5 days and should not exceed one week, but this is now the third week and I am still waiting.

**UPDATE**  (16.6.2021): The postdoc position has been revoked permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ask about the status. And you can ask again for an estimate of the time to resolution of any problems, though it may not be possible to give you an adequate answer.

I also hope that you are continuing to follow up with any other options you have. And if there aren't other options at the moment, all you can do is be patient - and try to develop other options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will send him a follow up email today. The problem does not seem to be peculiar to this position, but seem to be general. There are positions to which I have applied in February, and to which I have sent follow up after follow up, but still did not receive any reply, neither positive nor negative.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan unfortunately, it's common in academia not to reply to unsuccessful applicants. If you don't hear within a month, I would assume you have been unsuccessful.